# SQL query about to bind multiple elements to a specific one

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql

I am going to convert my current PostgreSQL database into a MongoDB version. For example, I have a table to record tweets, and another table to record multiple hashtags used by a specific tweet. What I wanna do is to use SQL to get a table like below and then export it as a .csv file so that I could import it to MongoDB.

Example:

```
2018-04-02 18:12:32 This plane has no outlet for me to charge my p...               [{'tag': 'GucciGarden', 'airline': 'American A...
```

The problem that I met is that I can get a .csv file contains json array like `"[{'tag': 'GucciGarden', 'airline': 'American A..."`, but it is a String type! And when I import it into MongoDB. The quote will be kept, which makes sth wrong.

And here is my SQL code:

```
    SELECT tweets.tweet_id,tweets.text,
        (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
        from (       
            SELECT tags.tag
            FROM
            tags
            WHERE tags.tweet_id=tweets.tweet_id
             ) d
        ) as Tags
    from tweets
```

Here is the result that I import into MongoDB:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac59c272221ade1185ec241"),
"tweet_id" : 9.80869021435351e+17.0,
"created_at" : "2018-04-02 18:06:13",
"text" : "RT @MiraSorvino: Brad Myles shares @Delta that awareness is working- 9,000 #humantrafficking cases identified by @polarisproject National H��",
"screen_name" : "MMexville",
"favorite_count" : 0.0,
"retweet_count" : 40.0,
"source" : "the public",
"tags" : "[{'tag': 'humantrafficking', 'airline': 'Delta Air Lines'}]"}
```

Comment: maybe will be faster to just use a text editor and remove the extra quotes before importing (if DB isn't huge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `[{'tag':` is not a valid json - you should have used double quotes and cast to json, eg:

let's say smth like your sample:

```
t=# create table c (i int, t text, j text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into c values(1,'text',$$[{'tag': 'GucciGarden'}]$$);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from c;
 i |  t   |            j
---+------+--------------------------
 1 | text | [{'tag': 'GucciGarden'}]
(1 row)
```

so then smth like your qry:

```
t=# select to_json(c) from (select i,t,replace(j,$$'$$,'"')::json j from c) c;
                     to_json
-------------------------------------------------
 {"i":1,"t":"text","j":[{"tag": "GucciGarden"}]}
(1 row)
```

of course you will have positive false replacements of single quotes, eg `'tag': 'Gucci's Garden'` will break the query logic, so you will have to make a more sophisticated replacement. probably with regular expressions to be neater.

Comment: Thank you so much!